# Invalid conversion error and invalid types

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash

Question:

> Write a program that implements a hash function on student roll no and categorize them in their families. Like 5000423, last 2 digits 23, 2+3=5, so belongs to family 5.

My attempt:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

const int tablesize= 20;

class hashentry
{
public:
    int key;
    int value;

    hashentry(int key,int value)
    {
        this->key=key;
        this->value=value;
    }
};

class hashmap
{
public:
    hashentry **table;
public:
    hashmap()
    {
        int table=new hashentry *[tablesize];
        for(int i=0;i<tablesize;i++)
        {
            table[i]=NULL;
        }
    }

    int hashfunc(int key)
    {
        return key%tablesize;
    }

    void insert(int key, int value)
    {
        int hash=hashfunc(key);
        while(table[hash]!=NULL && table[hash]->key!=key)
        {
            hash=hashfunc(hash+1);
        }
        table[hash]=new hashentry(key,value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    int key;
    int value;
    hashmap hash;
    cout<<"enter value";
    cin>>value;
    cout<<"enter key at which element is to be inserted";
    cin>>key;
    hash.insert(key,value);
    return 0;
}
```

Errors Captured :

```
In constructor 'hashmap::hashmap()':
invalid conversion from 'hashentry**' to 'int'
invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscript
```

Comment: Guessing the pointer could be a `long` in your program

Comment: `table` should be `this.table` in the constructor

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  Remove the `int` from `int table=new hashentry *[tablesize];` in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

```
int table=new hashentry *[tablesize];
```

The return type of `new hashentry *[tablesize]` is `hashentry**`. Since you are trying to assign it to an `int` variable, the compiler complains. Probably, you meant to omit the `int`, since you have already defined a member variable of the same name with the correct type, e.g. writing

```
table = new hashentry *[tablesize];
```

should do the trick.